# How to activate Windows Embedded Standard 2009?

Tags: windows, windows-activation, embedded, windows-embedded-2009

I downloaded Windows Embedded Standard 2009 from my MSDN subscription  and built a target image. I installed the image on an HP thin client.

The thin client says that I have and evaluation copy. How can I activate Windows and remove the "evaluation copy" text?

For example, I don't have access to the internet I would like build in target designer not evaluation copy.

Answer (score 0):

According to this document, it does not need activation, but only to have the key entered:

http://www.elbacom.com/embedded/products/wes/wes2009/overview

If you set it up using a trial key (as I suspect is the real problem), you can change it to your MSDN key at an elevated command prompt using the following command:

```
slmgr.vbs /ipk New_Product_Key
```

Comment: Is it possible to enter a product key after the trial key has expired? It appears that an expired trial key prevents WES2009 from starting, but it's possible to access the file system by booting from a secondary bootable media.

Comment: Actually, I've asked that as a [new question](http://superuser.com/q/1028089/199803).

Comment: I don't seem to have a file called `slmgr.vbs` anywhere on the system. Is it in an optional component? If so, what is the component called? I don't see any components with "license" or "slmgr" in their names.

Comment: This is incorrect. `slmgr.vbs` is not present before Windows Vista

Answer (score 0):

[This Microsoft post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/328874/how-to-change-the-volume-licensing-product-key-on-a-computer-that-is-r) contains two VBS scripts for activating Windows XP. The former one, originally designed for Windows XP SP1 and earlier, found to be compatible with Windows POSReady 2009. That is, `ChangeVLKey2600.vbs`,

```
' 
' WMI Script - ChangeVLKey.vbs
'
' This script changes the product key on the computer
'
'***************************************************************************

ON ERROR RESUME NEXT

if Wscript.arguments.count<1 then
   Wscript.echo "Script can't run without VolumeProductKey argument"
   Wscript.echo "Correct usage: Cscript ChangeVLKey.vbs ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PRSTU-WYQZX"
   Wscript.quit
end if

Dim VOL_PROD_KEY
VOL_PROD_KEY = Wscript.arguments.Item(0)
VOL_PROD_KEY = Replace(VOL_PROD_KEY,"-","") 'remove hyphens if any
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegDelete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WPAEvents\OOBETimer" 'delete OOBETimer registry value
for each Obj in GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").InstancesOf ("win32_WindowsProductActivation")

   result = Obj.SetProductKey (VOL_PROD_KEY)

   if err <> 0 then
      WScript.Echo Err.Description, "0x" & Hex(Err.Number)
      Err.Clear
   end if

Next
```

Just run the script and provide it with a valid POSReady 2009 key. [From here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYmJfW9DBb0), for example. Then reboot the machine and the timebomb should disappear

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use the Product Key that you used for installation of Windows Embedded Standard 2009. You have to enter the PID from the stickers that you get for putting on the target computers. Additionally to the license for Windows Embedded Standard 2009, you need a license for each target computer. Your distributor should be able to help you.